# Is there a bug in gftype.web's description of character widths?

Tags: tex-core, tex-history

Under https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mfware we find `gftype.web`.

On line 574 of `gftype.web` it says:

> The character width~|w| duplicates the information in the \.{TFM}
>   file; it is $**2^{24}**$ times the ratio of the true width to the font's
>   design size.

But in other places, for instance in `mf.web` under https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mf or in https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb02-1/tb02fuchstfm.pdf the TFM width is described as being a *fix_word* number scaled by 2^20 in design-size units.

In `mf.web` it says:

> The most important data type used here is a |@!fix_word|, which is a
>   32-bit representation of a binary fraction. A |fix_word| is a signed
>   quantity, with the two's complement of the entire word used to
>   represent negation. Of the 32 bits in a |fix_word|, exactly 12 are to
>   the left of the binary point; thus, the largest |fix_word| value is
>   $2048-2^{-20}$, and the smallest is $-2048$.

And `mf.web` also says:

> All other dimensions in the\/ \.{TFM} file are |fix_word|\kern-1pt\
>   numbers in design-size units.} Thus, for example, the value of
>   |param[6]|, which defines the \.{em} unit, is often the |fix_word|
>   value $2^{20}=1.0$, since many fonts have a design size equal to one
>   em.

And then `mf.web` describes the actual width stored in the GF-file:

> The character width~|w| duplicates the information in the \.{TFM}
>   file; it is a |fix_word| value relative to the design size, and it
>   should be independent of magnification.

Note that the first part of this text is the same as in `gftype.web`.

So should the formula $2^{24}$ really be $2^{20}$ instead?

Comment: It definitely seems a typo and `2^{20}` is meant. Look at section 61, where 1048576 is used as denominator and section 65 where *pix_ratio* is used when printing the postamble by `gftype`. In a tfm/gf pair I happen to have, a width is stated as `0.500002` in the tfm, which multiplied by 2^{20} yields `524290.097152`, which corresponds to the value `524290` in the gf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing better than doing an experiment. In TeX Live we find

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/yannisgr/rgrsc10.300gf
```

and the corresponding `tfm` file. Upon running `gftype`, we read

```
Character 0: dx 1376256 (21), width 524290 (20.75554), loc 8275
```

With `tftopl rgrsc10`, we read

```
(CHARACTER O 0
   (CHARWD R 0.500002)
   (CHARHT R 0.444445)
   (CHARIC R 0.027779)
   )
```

and 0.500002*2^20 = 524290.097152, which matches the value 524290 in the `gf` file.

Typo.

Comment: Does Knuth give out reward checks for bugs in these programs as well or is it just TeX and Metafont? (The same typo is also in gftodvi.web and gftopk.web.)

Comment: @nadder I guess he does.

Comment: @nadder I don't know whether there will be a reward check (I reported some even-more-minor typos in tangle.web etc earlier this year), but if I had to guess, I'd imagine he might give one out at the “errors in books” rate ($2.56 or thereabouts) rather than the “bugs in TeX and METAFONT” rate ($327.68). :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I would be super happy with any signed check from Knuth, I reported a possible bug a couple of years ago in TeX which was deemed borderline but not a bug, so maybe this is the time.